# apt-get doesn't stop on Ctrl-c, what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Occasionally I have connection problem with apt-get (typically because I use it behind a proxy and try to install/upgrade flash). I have been trying sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> but it would not stop. I thought it was something wrong with synaptic but obviously I just tried with a terminal and don't know how to stop it now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known bug: 
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=599007  
 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/578625

The [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=599007) mentions that even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> doesn't work.

Solution:

- Suspend the job: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Kill it: `sudo killall apt-get`